# How to prevent repeat statements for dice rolling

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent the statement printing out way too many times.

Output is supposed to look like this:

> Enter Seed: 100
>
> rolls: 6 6 2
>
> You rolled a pair
>
> rolls: 6 6 1
>
> You rolled a pair
>
> You are lucky

I'm not sure how to move around the boolean method or only call the boolean result so it doesn't print out the type of roll multiple times.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Triple {

    public static boolean rollType(int x, int y, int z){

        boolean lucky = false;

        if(x == y && y == z){
            System.out.println("You rolled a triple");
            lucky = true;
        }
        else if(x == y || y == z || x == z){
            System.out.println("You rolled a pair");
            lucky = true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You rolled nothing");
            lucky = false;
        }

        return lucky;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);  
       Random randGen = new Random();  // New random number generator
       int seedVal = 0;
       final int MAX_DICE = 8;

        //User input
       System.out.println("Enter Seed: ");
       seedVal = scnr.nextInt();
       randGen.setSeed(seedVal);

       int a1 = (randGen.nextInt(MAX_DICE)+1);
       int b1 = (randGen.nextInt(MAX_DICE)+1);
       int c1 = (randGen.nextInt(MAX_DICE)+1);

       int a2 = (randGen.nextInt(MAX_DICE)+1);
       int b2 = (randGen.nextInt(MAX_DICE)+1);
       int c2 = (randGen.nextInt(MAX_DICE)+1);

        // randGen.nextInt(MAX_DICE) yields 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 7
        // so + 1 makes that 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8
        System.out.println("rolls: " + a1 + " " + b1 + " " + c1);
        rollType(a1, b1, c1);
        System.out.println("rolls: " + a2 + " " + b2 + " " + c2);
        rollType(a2, b2, c2);

        if (rollType(a1, b1, c1) && rollType(a2, b2, c2)){  //work on how to fix it from printing twice THEN the boolean. should only print boolean.
            System.out.println("You are lucky");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You are NOT lucky");
        }

        return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the lines `rollType(a1, b1, c1);` and `rollType(a2, b2, c2);` that you have before your `if`. They are repeats since your `if` method calls them both no matter what.

This should fix your issue completely: now you only have  two calls to the `rollType` function so only two  sets of outputs

Update: Since you want a particular order, this fix will solve your problem. Add a `boolean` to your `rollType` function as such:

```
public static boolean rollType(int x, int y, int z, boolean print) {
    boolean lucky = false;
    if (x == y && y == z) {
        if (print) System.out.println("You rolled a triple");
        lucky = true;
    } else if (x == y || y == z || x == z) {
        if (print) System.out.println("You rolled a pair");
        lucky = true;
    } else {
        if (print) System.out.println("You rolled nothing");
        lucky = false;
    }
    return lucky;
}
```

Then use `rollType(a1, b1, c1, true)` and `rollType(a2, b2, c2, true)` the first time and `rollType(a1, b1, c1, false)` and `rollType(a2, b2, c2, false)` the second.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add how the output is supposed to look like. I re-edited my original post. Your suggestion makes total sense but it won't show the desired output order.